# How To: Hide and Show Tap Pages Using Vb.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to hide TapPage2 and TapPage3 when the form loaded and trying to show them back when the CheckBox1 is checked. I am able to hide the tappages using the codes below but when i click the checkbox, i am getting "System.ArgumentNullException: 'value cannot be null." error message. What should i do?

Here is the remove code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If Not IsNothing(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage2")) Then

        TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage2"))

    End If

    If Not IsNothing(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage3")) Then

        TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage3"))

    End If

End Sub
```

Here is the adding code:

```
 Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

      TabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage2"))
      TabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage3"))

 End Sub
```

Source Code: http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2014/08/20/windows-forms-how-to-hide-a-tab-page.aspx

Comment: Bet this has been answered,  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hide+and+show+tabpages

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't comment on spelling (I am a terrible speller and English is my native language) but it might help when you are searching that it is a Tab control and Tab pages. That is with a "b" at to end.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what this actually does (or tries to do):

```vb
TabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabControl1.TabPages("TabPage2"))
```

You are telling it to go to the `TabControl` and get the `TabPage` named "TabPage2" and then add that `TabPage` to the `TabControl`. How does that make sense? Firstly, if you could get that `TabPage` from the `TabControl` then why would you need to add it? It would already be in there. Secondly, you removed it in the first place so it's not in there, so how can you get it from in there?

Stop referring to the `TabPages` by name and use the fields generated for them by the designer the same way you use the field for the `TabControl`:

```vb
TabControl1.TabPages.Add(TabPage2)
```

You should be doing that when you remove them too. Also, get rid of that silly conditional code. How could those references possibly be `Nothing` if you added the `TabPages` yourself?

```vb
TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabPage2)
TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabPage3)
```